# how do I install pip/enable in python

Tags: python, pip

I have written 2 programs that run using pip. When I run them nothing happens(even though my code is correct). I have py 3.7 so therefore it should be pre-installed. help please!!

Comment: what error are you getting? and when running what command?

Comment: C:\Users\stoix\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/stoix/PycharmProjects/untitled/convertor
C:\Users\stoix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe: can't open file 'C:/Users/stoix/PycharmProjects/untitled/convertor': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Process finished with exit code 2 s       this is the only thing that appears in the console

Comment: that doesn't look like a pip error particularly. you'll need to share some of your code for people to be able to help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: yea I just realized that, might me because of the ide I will reinstall it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see your problem - according to your comment, this is your error message:

> C:\Users\stoix\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe
>   C:/Users/stoix/PycharmProjects/untitled/convertor
>   C:\Users\stoix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe: can't open file
>       'C:/Users/stoix/PycharmProjects/untitled/convertor': **[Errno 2] No such file or directory**

The error message is saying that there is `No such file or directory`, meaning the python file doesn't exist. If you look at the path, you can see that there is no extension to the file (such as `.py`). I think what is happening is that since the file passed in doesn't have an extension, python can't find the file. Try adding `.py` at the end of your file name and then run it or pass in your file name with `.py` at the end (if you are manually running this command).